# Create custom collection pagination that matches eloquent pagination? (Laravel 4.2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

I'm building a feature on a very large system that has everything built on the $builder->paginate(); function. By everything I mean, all the pagination and links are using the Builder instance.

The problem is that I have a **very** complicated query that, due to its complexity, needed to be a merge() of two Collection objects. Thus, the old pagination scheme won't work.

Besides this feature, all collections are generated using $query->queryPrams(....)->paginate(); and then passed to the view. Inside the view, we use $records->appends()->links() to get the links.

I understand that I'll need to use a custom paginator somehow. But what I'm trying to figure out is if it will let me paginate it using the method currently in place (paragraph 3 above) so that I don't have to write something custom *just* for this page.

TL;DR - I want to use Collections with the eloquent paginator because the rest of the site was already set up that way.

Comment: If you want to use the built in Laravel pagination, you probably will have to grab the paginated results from both objects you have, then mix them together afterwards.

Comment: decent idea, except that they wouldn't be merged properly and sorting would be disjointed.

Comment: You are planing to merge it anyways correct? What's the difference between merging them when using the paginated results against when not using it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Wouldn't paginating before the merge yield different results than after?